# How to calculate shipping charge based on product count and cart value?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In my Woocommerce store I want to calculate shipping charge based on product count and cart value eg if product count is more than 3 and cart value is less than 900 then shopping charge is 80. I want to do this type of calculations. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates','shipping_charge_product_count_cart_value',100,2);
function shipping_charge_product_count_cart_value($rates, $package) {

    global $woocommerce;

    // Get cart items
    $cart_items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
    $count_for_apply_shipping_charge = 0;

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if($cart_item['quantity'] > 3 && $cart_item['data']->get_price() < 900){
            $count_for_apply_shipping_charge += 1;
        }
      
    }

    if($count_for_apply_shipping_charge >= 1) {
        foreach ($rates as $rate) {

            //Set the price
            $rate->cost = 80 * $count_for_apply_shipping_charge;

        }

    }

    return $rates;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much dude, its working fine.. I want to add this for different zones. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like that? Here I add an example for the Florida state of the USA

```
if ( !empty($_POST['post_data'])  ) {
        parse_str($_POST['post_data'], $post_data);
        if ( !empty($post_data['shipping_state']) ) {
            $shipping_state = sanitize_text_field($post_data['shipping_state']);
            if ($shipping_state == 'FL') {
                $cart->add_fee('Florida Shipping', 25.00);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have four different shipping zone and I have to calculate shipping charge for each zone separately. Also have to add different COD charge for each zone.

Comment: Check your condition, apply the fees, and you can make an `array` for your zones, use the `in_array` function to if it exists, then imply your costs.

Comment: Thanks bro.  Lemme try with that. :)